# Query specific results from Realm array

Tags: swift, realm

I am a newbie to Realm and having some trouble. So I have a variable in a function that returns a list of users that are all "owners" like so:

```
    var namesOfUsers: String = list.users
        .flatMap({ $0 as? OwnersModel })
        .reduce("", combine: { (namesOfUsers, owner) -> String in
            guard let fullName = owner.name else {
                return namesOfUsers
            }

            return namesOfUsers + name + ", "
    })
```

Some of these "owners" are also "buyers" and some are not. How can I return a list of "owners" but exclude owners that are also "buyers"?

Comment: What does qualify an owner as a buyer? Could you share your `OwnersModel`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I'd recommend to use `flatMap` and `joinWithSeparator` instead of `reduce`.

```
var namesOfUsers: String = list.users
        .flatMap({ $0 as? OwnersModel })
        .filter({ !$0.isBuyer }) // Rejects buyers
        .flatMap({ $0.name })
        .joinWithSeparator(", ")
```

This also avoids that you get an extra comma at the end of your composed string, e.g. `"a, b"` instead `"a, b, "`.

Beside that if your collection is uniform and a lazy collection retrieved from Realm as e.g. an instance of `List` or `Results`, then you can use a `NSPredicate` instead to filter your objects, which would be executed directly on the database and is faster and less expensive.

```
let users: Results<OwnersModel> = …
users.filter("isBuyer == false")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I've been looking for!